# Show the last month as default in a dropdown list

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a dropdown list with months.
How Can I show the last month as default?
Example: This month is september, but I'd like to set as default the month august.

My view:

The dropdown list

```
<% 
    @date = Date.today
    @months = []
    (0..11).each do |m|
        @months << [@date.next_month(m).strftime("%B"), @date.next_month(m)]
    end
%>



<div class="col-md-8">

<%= f.select :datepay, options_for_select(@months), { :required => true, :onchange => "alert()" }  %>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your `@months` array does not contain the previous month.

So, include the previous month in your collection as follows:

```
@date = Date.today
  @months = []
  (-1..11).each do |m| #mark here I am starting the range from -1 i.e from August, 2016
    @months << [@date.next_month(m).strftime("%B"),@date.next_month(m)]
  end
```

Like you have used `next_month` to get next month, similarly `prev_month` can be used to get previous month.

```
<%= f.select :datepay, options_for_select(@months, @date.prev_month), { :required => true, :onchange => "alert()" }  %>
```

Comment: I think should be  `Date.today.prev_month` instead `Date.today.prev_month.strftime('%B')`

Comment: @BartekGładys correct & previous month should be an option in the `@months` collection!

Comment: @S_A this should work, can you add to your question what did you try ?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
options_for_select(@months)
```

to

```
options_for_select(@months, @date.prev_month(1))
```

This will add a default selection for the select box.